# QT Creator and strange code completion using smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, qt-creator

I'm using qtcreator (2.8.1) and there is some strange behaviour using smart pointer.

Have a look at this snippet:

```
class myclass {
public:
  void test() {};
};

....
std::shared_ptr<myclass> foo(new myclass);
foo->test();

std::unique_ptr<myclass> bar(new myclass);
bar->test();
```

If I type "foo->", the code completion window pops up, but if I type "bar->" nothing happens.

Any ideas why code completion only works with shared_ptrs and not with unique_ptrs?

UPDATE: It might be important to know that I'm using QT Creator with CMake and add_definitions(-std=c++11).

Comment: Are you using a generic project (makefile based), or a Qt-based one (off a .pro file)?

Comment: I'm using a Cmake based project. And yes - still the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's a bug.](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8937)

At some point in future, Qt Creator may start to use a real compiler frontend (probably *clang* which is pretty good for this kind of use) to do it's C++ parsing for autocompletion and syntax highlighting, but 2.8.1 has it's own imperfect C++ parser. C++ with it's turing-complete templates and preprosessor macros and decades of accumulated legacy crud is insanely complex to parse (and, as a result, slow if you do it fully), so bugs like this aren't all too surprising if parsing isn't done by an actual standards-compliant compiler.

Comment: All very true, but std::unique_ptr isn't some mega complex case to handle though :) its also very commonly used

Comment: @paulm Well, it requires parsing the templated return type of the operator overload of a template class, I wouldn't call that "easy". Also, when the parser parses the header file which contains `unique_ptr`, it needs to have the right defines (for C++11 etc), or `unique_ptr` will get excluded by pre-prosessor defines.

Comment: I can't understand why shared_ptr can have no issue yet unique_ptr is broken since unique_ptr impl is less complex than shared_ptr

Comment: @paulm Well, the discussion under linked bug report may provide some insight. Also, if you have personal interest on it, vote it up.